# undefined reference to vtable; virtual function issue

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, vtable

Suppose I override a virtual function in a child class with a declaration, and do not give a definition for the method. For example:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
}
class Derived : public Base
{
    void f();
}
```

(where I haven't given the definition of `f`). If I now use the class `Derived` - is it possible that i get a compiler error like "undefined reference to vtable..."?

Comment: You would certainly get an error if your code ever attempts to reference/call `Derived.f()`, but I think it would be a different one. "undefined reference to vtable" is, IIRC, usually a linker error, meaning that you are not including the object file or library containing the vtable for that class in your link stage...

Comment: Why don't you compile it and tell us?

Answer (score 0):

Not for `f`. You've explicitly said that the function will not have an implementation, which implies that derived classes must implement it.

However, if you declare a pure virtual destructor (e.g., `virtual ~Base()= 0`), you will have to provide a definition somewhere. In that case, if you don't, you will get a "undefined reference to vtable..." error.